# SQS triggers Lambda on Individual message delay delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I created below resources using CloudFormation

- SQS (DelayDelivery : 0)
- Lambda
- Roles
- LambdaFunctionEventSourceMapping (SQS Triggers a Lambda function)
- Logs

Resources created successfully.

When I send a message to SQS with Delay deliver for 30 seconds, SQS triggers Lambda instantaneously. Instead, it should have trigger after 30 seconds.
FYI : I am sending message using AWS console.

As per below link, it should have override the SQS delay to individual message delay.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: What are you using to generate messages for SQS? Why do you want to delay your lambda execution instead of delivery delay? In that case, you have to pay for an extra 30 seconds.

Comment: Messages are generate by PHP Application and sent to SQS.
I do not want the delay in Lambda execution.

When I send a message to SQS, a lambda is trigger. Even if a message has delay delivery

Comment: I've just realized that by using aws web interface. Same stuff, triggered lambda fn immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly a bug with the AWS console, because I encounter similar issue (lambda invoked instantaneously) when I send the message to SQS via AWS console. However, I can achieve the desired behaviour if I send the message to SQS via CLI:

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{account}/{sqs} --message-body "msg 1 delay 60 secs" --delay-seconds 60

aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{account}/{sqs} --message-body "msg 2 delay 30 secs" --delay-seconds 30
```

Then this is what I see in the lambda Cloudwatch log:

```
2019-02-19T02:26:36.189Z    510df77b-d1e5-5297-b0a0-a39eba727c61    msg 2 delay 30 secs
2019-02-19T02:26:36.189Z    510df77b-d1e5-5297-b0a0-a39eba727c61    sent 2019-02-19T02:26:06.124Z
2019-02-19T02:26:36.189Z    510df77b-d1e5-5297-b0a0-a39eba727c61    1st receive 2019-02-19T02:26:36.124Z

2019-02-19T02:26:57.729Z    fedcb590-2e14-596a-bc4b-e17545a46d91    msg 1 delay 60 secs
2019-02-19T02:26:57.729Z    fedcb590-2e14-596a-bc4b-e17545a46d91    sent 2019-02-19T02:25:57.667Z
2019-02-19T02:26:57.729Z    fedcb590-2e14-596a-bc4b-e17545a46d91    1st receive 2019-02-19T02:26:57.667Z
```

As you can see from the log, the messages delivery are properly delayed, and lambdas are only invoked once the message is received.